# Show error messages in div container for validations using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to show error messages in `div` container using jQuery for validation.

So, instead of an alert message, I want to show the error message after every control where ever the validation fails.

```
if (name == '' || email == '' || mobile == '' || password == '' || cpassword == '') {
var errName = document.getElementByID("name");
errName.innerHTML += "Please enter name";
errName.innerHTML += ".red {color:red;}";
document.getElementByID("name").val = errName;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a jquery validation plugin.

Comment: where issue we will be suggesting?

Comment: Actually, I am new to Jquery. Any ways ,I will try doing that. Thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A more pure jQuery approach would be as shown below

jQuery Code

```
if (name == '' || email == '' || mobile == '' || password == '' || cpassword == '') {
   var errName = $("#name"); //Element selector
   errName.html("Please enter name"); // Put the message content inside div
   errName.addClass('error-msg'); //add a class to the element
}
```

CSS:

```
.error-msg{
   background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

**Update:**
      You can even combine the jQuery methods on any selector. Whenever we apply a jQuery menthod on any selector, it returns a "this" pointer, so we can combine multiple methods and apply them to a selector using a single statement. This is called "chaining"

Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp

```
if (name == '' || email == '' || mobile == '' || password == '' || cpassword == '') {
       $("#name").html("Please enter name")
                 .addClass("error-msg"); // chained methods
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (name == '' || email == '' || mobile == '' || password == '' || cpassword == '') {
   var errName = $("#name"); //get element by ID
   errName.append("Please enter name"); //append information to #name
   errName.attr("style", "background-color: red;"); //add a style attribute
}
```

*Edit*: or you could do it like so:

```
if (name == '' || email == '' || mobile == '' || password == '' || cpassword == '') {
   var errName = $("#name"); //get element by ID
   errName.append("Please enter name"); //append information to #name
   errName.attr("class", "alert"); //add a class to the element
}
```

Then you will have an `.alert` class. This makes it possible for you to use this class in your CSS file.

```
.alert {
   background-color: #FF0000;
}
```